# Configure Ember CLI Mirage to support liverload for mirage configuration with Embroider

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I have an [Ember.js](https://emberjs.com/) application, which uses [Embroider](https://github.com/embroider-build/embroider) and [Ember CLI Mirage](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/). Sadly live-reload is not working for Mirage configuration changes. A change to Mirage configuration does not trigger a rebuild. It seems as if `mirage/` folder is not watched.

I reproduced this issue in a newly created Ember application using Ember CLI v4.1 with the `--embroider` flag. So it is not related to any special configuration of my application.

Do I need to configure Embroider somehow to watch `mirage/` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this probably related to: https://github.com/embroider-build/embroider/issues/972

and there could certainly be more documentation, but there was a similar issue with Docfy here: https://github.com/josemarluedke/docfy/issues/110

Does this work with mirage?:

```
EMBROIDER_REBUILD_ADDONS='ember-cli-mirage' ember s
```